# proftpd saving %u to var and rewrite it afterwards

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, proftpd

currently working on an ftp proxy with [ProFTPD](https://github.com/proftpd).

Our setup is pretty much still the same as in this [issue](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy/issues/119).

However, we struggle to make use of the username.
As we want to hide/transport the target server in the username we
do an rewrite on the username to get it cleaned up.

So far so good, we can use the clean username.
To do an LDAP authentication.

**However** we are still in need of the targetserver string that was in the username before the rewrite.

Any information on how to:

- save the original username to a environment variable before it is rewritten (and prevent the env variable to be rewritten as well)
- use the ProFTPD notes (read about it but somehow failed to find and docs on it)
- access the original username (not the rewritten one)
- any other information how to accomplish hiding username and targetserver in the connection and using it

are very welcome.

Maybe there is some kind of technique that we do use in the wrong way or a technique that we failed to use so far.

Edit:

Regarding @Castaglia

Was said we do have 2 infos in the original username. ADuser@RemoteServer.

Withe the ADuser we want to establish an LDAP authentication. With the RemoteServer info we want to connect to a remote server with credentials we queried from MySQL.

What we struggle with right now is making use of both infos. With the rewrite we get a clean user but loose the server.

So what we are looking for is some sort of option to save the original string to a var. And rewrite it 2 times. One time into a userstring to authenticate ans one time into a server name to know which server the user wants to connect to.

Comment: Where/how, exactly, are you trying to use the original username?  In a SQL query, or in an `ExtendedLog`, or...?

Comment: Taget would be to use it in a SQL query. Where we get rid of the username part and use the targetserver still in the original username.

Comment: The `%U` variable _should_ provide the original value from the `USER` command sent by the client; if that does not work, please update your post to show the config using this, and the result.

Comment: Your config is also using `mod_rewrite` to _rewrite/modify_ the `USER` command sent; are you hoping/wanting to get the _unmodified_ value there?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I updated the question and hope it clears up what we try to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interested party, this is how we (me and Daniel) solved it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCondition %m USER
  RewriteRule ^(.*#)?([0-9A-Za-z]+)(@)?(.*)? $2
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ldap.c>
  LDAPServer ...
  ...
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_sql.c>
  SQLBackend mysql
  SQLConnectInfo ...
  SQLLog USER server_token
  SQLNamedQuery server_token UPDATE "buffer_token='%{note:mod_rewrite.$4}' WHERE username = '%U'" users
  SQLAuthenticate off
  SQLNamedQuery get-url  SELECT "concat('ftp://',ftp_username, ':', ftp_password, '@', ftp_servername) FROM users inner join server_user on users.id = user_id inner join servers on servers.id = server_id WHERE username = '%U' and token = buffer_token"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
...
</IfModule>
ProxyReverseServers sql:/get-url
```

Comment: Hi there, please avoid to paste whole code / config but prefer to highlight useful part and gives some explaination on how you solved it

Comment: Hello @Arount, thanks for your suggestion. Fabian edited the Answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that to get what you want to achieve, you might try the following.

First, modify the `RewriteRule` slightly, in order to capture the *second* part of your `USER` command (*e.g.* "RemoteServer"), thus:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCondition %m USER
  RewriteRule ^(.*#)?([0-9A-Za-z]+)(@)?(.*)? $2
</IfModule>
```

Next, in your SQL query configuration, use a *note* reference to retrieve that regex group:

```
<IfModule mod_sql.c>
  ...
  SQLConnectInfo ... PERCONNECTION
  ...
  SQLNamedQuery get-url SELECT "concat('ftp://',ftp_username, ':', ftp_password, '@', ftp_servername) FROM users ... WHERE concat(username, '@', token) = '%{note:mod_rewrite.$4}'"
  ...
</IfModule>
```

That `%{note:mod_rewrite.$4}` notation says "interpolate the value of the session note stored under the key 'mod_rewrite.$4'".  And `mod_rewrite` stashes/records the *groups* of the matched `RewriteRule` in those session notes; the `$N` uses a 1-based index, thus `$1` for the first group,
 `$2` for the second group (which would be the "ADuser" value in your example `USER` command), `$3` for the third group, *etc*.

I've updated my answer to *also* include the use of the "PERCONNECTION" [`SQLConnectInfo`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html#SQLConnectInfo) policy.  Why?  This tells the `mod_sql` module to connect to the SQL database *when a client connects*, rather than waiting until the client has provided all of the necessary credentials.  Due to the way that `mod_rewrite` stashes its notes about the captured regex groups, this is necessary: those notes are only captured *for the duration of that command only* (*i.e.* in your case, only the `USER` command).  Thus we want to *use* the configured SQL statement when the `USER` command is processed, since that is when that `%{note:mod_rewrite.$4}` reference will be valid.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My colleague solved the issue: We ware now able to connect the users via LDAP and forward the information to the SQL query.

However, the attempt above helped a great deal to find the correct solution but doesn't work 'as is'.

This is because the note is empty again by the time the mysql query gets build/executed. So we used a named query to write a log by the time of the login and use this information later to determine the correct 'session'. And eventually get the credentials and server address.